# Self sizing UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to build a `UICollectionView` that has self-sizing `UICollectionViewCells`.  I am using a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UITableView` because I'd like a list view on iPhone and a grid view on iPad.

I've setup a sample project [here](https://github.com/kaler/SelfSizingCollectionView).

It is the simplest code possible.  A `UICollectionView` that is loaded from a Storyboard.  There is one `UICollectionViewCell` with one `UILabel`.  The `UILabel` has constraints that pin it to the edges of the cell.

The `UICollectionView` has a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  If I set `itemSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`, I get constraint errors.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image: Cell doesn't self size]

The code in the ViewController is very straight forward:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

    // MARK: - view lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // This causes constaint errors.
            //            collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
            //            collectionViewFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)

        guard let itemCell = cell as? ItemCell else {
            return cell
        }

        itemCell.label.text = "blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Have you tried setting `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints` to `false` on the cell/label?

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints` is set to false in the Storyboard.  I'm not seeing any constraint errors.

Comment: When I add `collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` then I get:

`The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your viewDidLoad().

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: I had to change my ViewController to inherit from UICollectionViewController rather than UIViewController to set this.  But it didn't help.